# AWSでCloudWatchAgentを使ってカスタムメトリクスを集めたいが、コンソールに表示されません(取得できない）

Tags: windows, aws-cloudwatch

以下設定したこと

- EC2にCloudWatchAgentをインストール
- 手動で作成したjsonファイルでagent起動済み(下記に記載。exe名は省略しています。)
- ロールでAmazonEC2RoleforSSM,CloudWatchAgentServerPolicyをEC２にアタッチ済み

状況

- EC2からインターネットアクセス可能なことを確認
- CloudWatchAgent、SSMは動いていることを確認

コンソールでCloudWatchメトリクスを見に行っても、デフォルト名前空間すらない状態でメトリクスが取得できていないようです。何か対処法をご存じの方がいましたらお力をお貸しください。

```js
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "windows_events": {
                "collect_list":[
                    {
                    "event_format": "xml",
                    "event_levels": [
                        "VERBOSE",
                        "INFORMATION",
                        "WARNING",
                        "ERROR",
                        "CRITICAL"
                    ],
                    "event_name": "Application",
                    "log_group_name": "test0306-logs",
                    "log_stream_name": "Application_Log",
                    "retention_in_days": 365
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "System": {
                "measurement": [
                    "Processor Queue Length"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,

                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "LogicalDisk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Free Space"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Memory": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Committed Bytes In Use"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "procstat": [
                {
                    "exe": "",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "exe": "amazon-cloudwatch-agent",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "exe": "",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "exe": "",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "exe": "",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "exe": "",
                    "measurement" : [
                        "pid_count"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "statsd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "service_address": ":8125"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [CloudWatch エージェントのログファイル](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-cannot-start) には何かヒントがありませんか？ 判断に迷うなら質問文に記載してください。原因が判明したら、その原因を自己回答してください。